# Multiplicação de matrizes e armazenar em outra matriz?

Tags: c, matriz

Seja uma função que receba três matrizes de valores inteiros A, B e C,
e dois inteiros `n` e `m` representando a quantidade de linhas e de colunas dessas matrizes. Essa função deve calcular a multiplicação das matrizes A e B e armazenar o resultado na matriz C.

Essa e a minha função:

```
void multiplicacao(int matA[] [MAX], int na, int ma, int matB[] [MAX],int nb, int mb, int matC [] [MAX], int nc, int mc)  
{  

int i , j;

if (na == nb && nb == nc && na == nc && ma == mb && mb == mc && ma == mc)
{
    for (i =0; i < na ;i ++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < ma ;j ++)
        {
           printf (" Digite matA [%d][%d]: ",i , j) ;
           scanf ("%d",&matA [i][j]) ;
        }
    }

    for (i =0; i < nb ;i ++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < mb ;j ++)
        {
           printf (" Digite matB [%d][%d]: ",i , j) ;
           scanf ("%d",&matB [i][j]) ;
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<nb && i<na; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<nb && j<na; i++)
        {
            matC[i][j]= (matA[i][j]) * (matB[i][j]);
        }
        printf("%d \n",matC[i][j] );
    }
}

}
```

Só que não está compilando, está dando "Falha de segmentação (imagem do núcleo gravada)". O que está errado? A minha lógica também está certa para armazenar em  C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma coisa é ler as matrizes do usuário, outra é multiplicá-las e outra é exibi-la. A função que multiplica as matrizes não deve fazer mais do que a multiplicação propriamente dita. O motivo para isso é que se você quiser multiplicar matrizes lidas de um arquivo ou produzidas como resultado de algum outro processo, isso não será possível se você estiver lendo elas do usuário. A mesma coisa se você quiser mostrar uma matriz sem ter efetuado multiplicação.

As funções de ler e mostrar uma matriz são essas:

```
void ler_matriz(int mat[][MAX], int n, int m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf("Digite mat[%d][%d]: ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void mostrar_matriz(int mat[][MAX], int n, int m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Vamos observar essa condição:

```
na == nb && nb == nc && na == nc
```

O `na == nc` é desnecessário. O mesmo pode ser dito do `ma == mc`.

Um outro problema no seu código é isso:

```
    for(j=0; j<nb && j<na; i++)
```

Você está utilizando `j` como variável do laço, mas está incrementando o `i`.

Você também pode usar um retorno inteiro para representar erro. Vamos colocar que 0 é ok e 1 é erro de tamanho das matrizes.

Assim sendo, se você queria era apenas multiplicar os elementos nas mesmas posições, então:

```
int multiplicar_elementos(
        int matA[][MAX], int na, int ma,
        int matB[][MAX], int nb, int mb,
        int matC[][MAX], int nc, int mc)
{  

    if (na != nb || nb != nc || ma != mb || mb != mc) return 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < na; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; k < ma; j++) {
            matC[i][j] = matA[i][j] * matB[i][j];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Entretanto, se a sua ideia é implementar o algoritmo de [multiplicação de matrizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication), o problema aqui é maior. Nesse caso, as matrizes não têm os mesmos tamanhos. A quantidade de linhas da primeira matriz é igual a quantidade de colunas (e não de linhas) da segunda. Ou seja, a menos que você esteja multiplicando matrizes quadradas, elas **não** devem ter os mesmos tamanhos.

O produto de uma matriz de dimensões *A x B* por uma *B x C* dá em uma matriz *A x C*.

Como você está multiplicando uma matriz *`na` x `ma`* por uma *`nb` x `mb`* para dar uma *`nc` x `mc`*, então `ma` deve ser igual a `nb`, `na` deve ser igual a `nc` e `mb` deve ser igual a `mc`.

Com isso, podemos reduzir os seis números de tamanhos de matriz a apenas três.

O algoritmo de multiplicação de matrizes vai precisar de três laços. O motivo disso é que na matriz resultante, cada célula contém a soma dos produtos dos elementos de uma linha da primeira matriz pelos elementos de uma coluna da segunda. Dessa forma, para preencher cada célula da terceira matriz, você vai precisar de um laço interno percorrendo a linha da primeira e a coluna da segunda ao mesmo tempo. Por fora desse laço interno, você precisará de outros dois para visitar cada célula da terceira matriz.

O seu código arrumado para multiplicar matrizes fica assim:

```
int multiplicar_matrizes(
        int matA[][MAX], int na, int ma,
        int matB[][MAX], int nb, int mb,
        int matC[][MAX], int nc, int mc)
{  

    if (ma != nb || na != nc || mb != mc) return 1;

    int a = na, b = ma, c = mb;

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < c; k++) {
            matC[i][k] = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
                matC[i][k] += matA[i][j] * matB[j][k];
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```